# How to prove mathematically a sequence as a Cauchy sequence in general?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

How to take epsilon and what exactly do one mean by the existence of natural number. Definition is itself a vague to me.

Can anyone help me with an mathematical algorithm for proving a Cauchy sequence which would be generla to every problem I consider?

Thank you well in advance.

Comment: No such algorithm can exist.

Comment: I'm afraid the problem is that you don't understand the definition. So you'd be better advised to choose an example, and tell us where exactly you don't understand it.

Comment: @Professor Vector +1. I would be free to advise you start with something simple, e.g $a_n=\frac {1}{n}$ and see how far you can go. Pick a tiny number $\varepsilon \gt 0$ and see at which point all $a_n$ start getting closer to each other than the chosen number $\varepsilon$...

Answer (score 2):

I definitely understand. It can take awhile to get used to the reasoning involved in Real Analysis. A Cauchy sequence is a sequence whose terms eventually start clustering together. That is they eventually start getting arbitrarily close together. For real numbers, a sequence is Cauchy if and only if it converges. If you think about it, a convergent sequence eventually starts clustering around its limit, and so all the terms that are clustering near the limit point are therefore also clustered near each other. The way to prove a sequence is Cauchy is to show that given any positive number, no matter how small, eventually the terms of that sequence are within that distance of each other, and stay within that distance of each other. Consider the following definition of a Cauchy sequence

$$\text{For all } \xi > 0, \text{ there exists an } N\in\mathbb{N} \text{ such that } n,m \geq N \text{ implies } \left|x_n - x_m\right| < \xi$$

$ \\ $

The absolute value is a good way of expressing distance, that is, $|x-y|$ can be thought of as the distance between the points $x$ and $y$

Think of the $\xi$ as a challenge. Somebody gives you $\xi$, say $\xi = .001$ and says "show me the terms of the sequence are eventually always within $.001$ of each other. The $n,m \geq N$ corresponds to the "eventually" part, and the number $N$ is the cutoff point. That is, if you pick any two terms of the sequence that are higher than $N$ they will be within $.001$ of each other. Your goal is to find the cut-off point $N$. You have to show that you can find such an $N$ for any $\xi > 0$. I realize it can be hard thinking in this way but I can promise you with practice it will get easier. I'm afraid there is no algorithm that one can use, but as a general rule the triangle inequality can frequently be helpful.

Comment: I am trying to understand the definition  but still I am not able to convince myself that 'okay! I understood' . So, I will solve initially by taking two terms n and m and then will apply triangle inequality to get the |xn-xm| < say Y.  What actually must be the form of  this Y? Whether Y must be written in some form of n or m? Whether this Y should be written as the lowest possible value? How to proceed next to find N? Is there some relation that has to be obtained between N and epsilon?  Sorry,I had to put all my questions out in a single shot. But I am frustrated out.

Comment: If I have Y=1/2^n. Can I write it also as |xn-xm|<1/n. Am I right?

Comment: Suppose |xn-xm|< 1/2^n can i write this as |xn-xm|<1/n ? Because on witing so I can relate H and Epsilon.

Comment: @MB17 Can you update your question or post as a comment here both what specific sequence you are looking at and what H is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's give it a try to explain the definition of a Cauchy sequence with a simple example like $a_n=\frac1n$: we need to construct for *any* given $\epsilon>0$ a number $N(\epsilon)$ so that $|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$, as soon as both $n$ and $m$ are $>N(\epsilon)$. But if $n>N(\epsilon)$ and $m>N(\epsilon)$, $\frac1n<\frac1{N(\epsilon)}$ and $\frac1m<\frac1{N(\epsilon)}$, so $$|a_n-a_m|=\left|\frac1n-\frac1m\right|\le\frac1n+\frac1m<\frac2{N(\epsilon)},$$ and that's certainly $<\epsilon$, if only $N(\epsilon)>\frac2\epsilon$.

Comment: So, I can choose any values for epsilon greater than 0. Suppose I choose epsilon=0.1 and n=3 and m=4 Clearly |an-am|<0.1 and obviously N must be equal to 2. But from the above expression which you provided N>2/0.1 i.e N>20. How is that possible? I know my reasoning is completely out of order. But I am not getting where am I wrong. @David Reed

Comment: @David Reed The idea is to choose $N(\epsilon)$ so that we can **guarantee** that $|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$ for $n,m>N(\epsilon)$. Those values may be far on the safe side, naturally. In this simple case, we certainly could do better, but often, we don't have more than such crude estimates. But if you only want to prove convergence, it wouldn't make much sense to look for the optimal (smallest) value of  $N(\epsilon)$.

Comment: @David Reed Okay. that means I have to search some larger values for N. I was trying to solve by taking different examples. And I came across one problem and I am stuck there. Given |an - a(n+1)|< n^2/2^n how to prove as this Cauchy?